# jQuery new element creation not working on IE8 Browser

Tags: jquery, html, object, element

I am creating an element **DIV** with html content like bellow,

```
var newDiv = $("<div />",{
   "class": "container",
   "width":234,
   "height":300,
   "html":"Testing <b>dynamic</b> content"
});
$("body").append(newDiv);
```

Above code is working fine for the browser chrome, safari, mozilla but not working in IE8. I am getting error as:

> "Object doesn't support this property or method"

I used jQuery version 1.6

Any alternate script or ie8 fix is available?

Comment: which property or method?

Answer (score 2):

```
var newDiv = $("<div />",{
   class: "container",
   width:234,
   height:300,
   html:"Testing <b>dynamic</b> content"
});
$("body").append(newDiv);
```